# ARM64 Neon loading single element

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, arm64, neon

What am I missing?
I am getting this error: Unknown symbolic operand name in inline assembly string.

```
#if defined(__MATH_NEON_64)
    int x0 = 4;
    const int* pX0 = &x0;
    asm(
    "ld1.1s {v0}, [%[x0]] \n\t"
    :"+r"(pX0) :: "memory");
#endif
```

EDIT:
ok this compiles now.

```
#if defined(__MATH_NEON_64)
    int x0 = 4;
    const int* pX0 = &x0;
    asm(
    "ld1.2s {v0}, [%[x0]] \n\t"
    :[x0] "+r" (pX0) :: "v0", "memory");
#endif
```

Comment: `%[foo]` refers to an operand named `foo`, like you could name with `[foo] "+r" (pX0)`, rather than a numbered operand.  IDK if you meant to write `%x0` to use an `x` modifier with `%0` (if that's a thing), or what, but you didn't name an operand `[x0]`.

Comment: Are you trying to learn inline asm?  If you just want to use ARM64 SIMD, probably best to just use intrinsics instead of inline asm at all.  (Unless there's a case where the compiler makes sub-optimal asm.)  This is missing a clobber on `v0`, which you write without telling the compiler about.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert my asm code previously written for ARM32 to ARM64. 
I got confused on some of the syntax changes. Thanks for the replies!!

Comment: Probably best to rewrite with intrinsics, especially if the original code had unsafe stuff like writing to `q0` without telling the compiler about it.  Perhaps you were compiling without telling the compiler the CPU even had NEON?  But for ARM64, SIMD registers are baseline I think, so the compiler might already be using vector regs to copy around local vars.

Comment: ok, I will have a look at the intrinsic functions.